# Java: TCP Socket Data loss

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a Server (and of course a Client) for my Game. It is developed with Java and no extra Libs
or external work. The Client and Server connection is currently setup, that it sends a defined number of bytes (512) as "
packages"
. Each package has an ID for its Type(1 byte) and a body for its data (511 bytes). In general this connection seems to work. The issue I currently face, is that when I send a large a
amount of Data (the map ~ 10kb ~ 1300 packges) as fast as possible, I seem to lose messages or receives messages with an error (for example: wrong package-ID). I can't seem to figure out why this happens. As I understands it, the sockets in Java uses the TCP
Protocol, which is as far as I know supposed to prevent those issues.

This is the important (in my opinion) part of the server:

```
void sendToClient(Queue<DataPackage> packages) {
    if(isConnected()){
        try {
            while(!packages.isEmpty()){
                this.out.write(packages.get().getByteData());
                packages.remove();
                this.out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(!isConnected()){
                if(!ended){
                    ended = true;
                    server.getServerManager().getEventManager().publishServerEvent(new ServerLostConnectionToClientEvent(id, connection));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the important (in my opinion) part of the client:

```
private void acceptData() throws UnsupportedPackageException {
    byte[] income = new byte[DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH];
    try {
        for(int length = in.read(income); length!=-1 && isConnected(); length = in.read(income)){
            income = Arrays.copyOf(income, DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH);   

            DataPackage dataPackage = null;
            try {
                dataPackage = new DataPackage(income, length);
            } catch (Exception ea) {ea.printStackTrace();}

            if(dataPackage!=null){

                if(!this.dataStreams.containsKey(dataPackage.getId())) this.dataStreams.put(dataPackage.getId(), new Queue<DataPackage>());
                Queue<DataPackage> dataStream = dataStreams.get(dataPackage.getId());
                if(dataPackage.isEnd()) {
                    this.dataStreams.remove(dataPackage.getId());   
                    handNewDataPackage(dataPackage, dataStream);
                }                   
            }

            income = new byte[DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH];
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(this.client.run() && !ended){
            this.client.endClient();
            this.client.connectionLost(new ClientLostConnectionToServerEvent(this.socket));
        }
        ended = true;
    }
}
```

This is how I setup the connection:

```
socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(false);
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH);
        socket.setSendBufferSize(DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH);

        this.out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH);
        this.in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), DataPackage.MAXPACKAGELENGTH);
```

You can view the entire project (if you want) here: https://github.com/reschiram/Game (newest Branch: G-9)

I am sorry if this looks lke it is just another duplicate question on how to code a java socket. I too have seen several similar question here, but none seem to fit my issue entirely (or helped me fixing it).

Comment: have you thought about using netty  ?? https://github.com/netty/netty

Comment: Are you expecting to handle a single `read()` call for each `write()` or `send()` call on the server? TCP/IP doesn't work like that - it's a *streaming* protocol, so you should treat the data as a stream. If you want to send a sequence of "packages" you'll need to make sure there's something *in the data* to indicate where each package starts and ends. Typically you do that via a length prefix before the data of the package, but there are alternatives depending on what you need to achieve.

Comment: You are assuming that each read fills the buffer. That's not in the contract. See the Javadoc. You may want to try `DataInputStream.readFully()`. And `isConnected()` isn't a valid test for end of stream or a lost connection.

Comment: isConnected() is a custom method with works with a heartbeat to test wether or not the connecting is stil "alive"

Comment: Works with a custom method how? A heartbeat method would have to both send and receive, and that runs the risk of entangling he heartbeat data with the data you are trying to receive here.

Comment: All packages (byte arrays I send) have the same length - so is there a need to indicate the length of the package when it is always MAXPACKAGELENGTH (512 bytes)

Comment: The server goes through a loop checking if it has to send new Queues of Packages. Once it is done it sends a heartbeat message. I am not sure,but I thought his way it would not interfere

Comment: I would recommend against using a heartbeat. TCP itself doesn't have one, nor HTTP, FTP, POP3, SMTP,  or any other major IP application protocol I am aware of, and they are difficult to implement correctly. A read timeout is generally sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @user207421 DataInputStream.readFully() fixed my problem!